# rails app not starting, 'ActiveSupport::Deprection' error on assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My (previously working) app all of a sudden wont start on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I'm getting the strange error 'ActiveSupport::Deprection', looks like a mis-spelling of Deprecation?

Comment: Which version of Rails do you have in yours app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be something to do with rails 4.2.3 (released a few weeks ago).  Changing to Rails = 4.2.2 in the Gemfile has fixed the issue for now.  Will post a better answer when I figure out what's happened